# javascript syntax error: uncaught expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a web application, where I got a simple problem which I can't solve. I've put the code which creates the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/rkumarnirmal/5w3FG/

What's problem with the second alert() which should display this answer

```
current
```

The problem is:

```
var b = '.something';
var c = $(b).attr("id");
alert(c);
```

is not showing the id.

But, When I give

```
var c = $('.something').attr("id");
alert(c);
```

It works. Have I done anything wrong with the selector?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your fiddle is actually different.

```
var b = "." + a.split(/\s+/).pop();
```

works because it's a `.` followed by a class name. You included both `"` and `'` in the string which means `'` is part of the selector (which is a syntax error).

You can pass a string like `$("abc")` in which `abc` is the selector. If you use a variable like this:

```
var selector = "abc";  // the selector abc stored in a variable as a string
$(selector);           // the selector is passed to jQuery
```

then you shouldn't use additional `'`s or `"`s.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
var a = $('#current').attr("class");
var b = "."+a.split(/\s+/).pop(); // not "'."+a.split(/\s+/).pop()+"'";
    alert(b);
var c = $(b).attr("id");
    alert(c);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5w3FG/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = $('#current').attr("class");
var b = "." + a.split(/\s+/).pop();
alert(b);
var c = $(b).attr("id");

alert(c);
```